# In pandas, how to replace all zero values with the last non zero value which is not more than 4 rows up, without a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, fill, zero

If one of my dataframe columns looks like this:

```
5
0
0
0
0
0
6
0
```

It should look like this

```
5
5
5
5
5
0
6
6
```

I know how to do it with a loop and a counter, but I am wondering how to do it without a for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need to mask, there is the method [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) that allows you to specify `limit` and `method='ffill'`. Going through `Nan`also converts to float which is not needed.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0]})

# Replace 0s with forward fill and limit set to 4 elements
df2 = df.replace(0, limit=4, method='ffill')

print(df)

   a
0  5
1  5
2  5
3  5
4  5
5  0
6  6
7  6
```

Comment: Yeah you avoid conversion to float due to NaN

Answer (score 4):

you can `mask` if value is 0 to get nan, use [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) with the limit parameter and `fillna` the rest with 0

```
s = pd.Series([5,0,0,0,0,0,6,0])
s_ = s.mask(s.eq(0)).ffill(limit=4).fillna(0)
print (s_)
0    5.0
1    5.0
2    5.0
3    5.0
4    5.0
5    0.0
6    6.0
7    6.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: brilliant answer, I never remember to use the args from fffill or bfill thanks for the reminder